# Freemarker string escaping doesn't work with default operator

Tags: freemarker

We use Freemarker 2.3.20 and came across a strange behavior, when using the default operator together with string escaping like this:

```
${picture.@author[0]!""?js_string}
```

in this case, quotes in the authors value are not escaped if !"" is present.

We need to check first for the value and can't use the default op:

```
<#if picture.@author[0]??>${picture.@author[0]?js_string}</#if>
```

this is quite ugly and blown up code.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the operator precedences. `${picture.@author[0]!""?js_string}` means `${picture.@author[0]!(""?js_string)}`. What you want is `${(picture.@author[0]!"")?js_string}`.